# Group id is changed automatically when creating a new group with Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have multiple domains in Office 365, and enabled custom domain as the default domain and the default accepted domain in Office 365, when I posted a create group request with Graph API, and I got the group response with xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com email, but after a few seconds, I tried to get the group with group id again, the group email was changed to custom domain. So I want to know why this happened? and how to prevent this issue?

I tried to create the Office 365 group in Office 365 portal and exchange admin center, and it works well.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you.

Long

Answer (score 1):

Is the response in the group referring to a ProxyAddress with the secondary SMTP using the .onmicrosoft.com? That's normal to where if you update the default domain name, you may still see the .onmicrosoft.com can be used to route the mail in case the custom domain is removed to prevent losing access to mail.

If you don't want the secondary SMTP to be using the .onmicrosoft.com, you will have to manually update it.

You can refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/choose-domain-to-create-groups?view=o365-worldwide

Hope that helps.
-Eliza

Comment: Thank you Eliza, Yes, it's available to choose domain to create group with UI, but it's not available by the Graph API, and the response is not correct from the first time, so it's not good to the developer because we need to query multiple time to get the correct group Id:(